# Prove limsup equality with function of sequence

Tags: calculus, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{ y_{k}\}_{k}$ a positive sequence and 
$\alpha$ a scalar continuous function s.t. $\alpha(0) =0$
and $\alpha(s) > s$ for every $s >0$.

I would like to prove the following equality:

$\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha(y_k) = \alpha(\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} y_k) $

Are there any other assumptions that I should take under consideration?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoule add the condition : $\alpha(s)$ is monotone increasing .

W.L.G, we may assume the sequence $\{ y_{k}\}$ is bounded.
First, we prove 
$$\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} \alpha(y_k)\geq\alpha(\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} y_k).$$
For the sequence $\{ y_{k}\}$, there exists subsequence $\{ y_{k_{j}}\}$ such that 
 $$\lim_{j\to\infty}y_{k_{j}}=\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} y_k:=y,$$
due to the continuity of $\alpha(s)$, we have 
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\alpha(y_{k_{j}})=\alpha(y),$$
obviously, $$\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} \alpha(y_k)\geq\lim_{j\to\infty}\alpha(y_{k_{j}})=\alpha(y)=\alpha(\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} y_k).$$
(because $\{\alpha(y_{k_{j}})\}$ is subsequence of $\{\alpha(y_{k})\}$.)
Then we show 
$$\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} \alpha(y_k)\leq\alpha(\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} y_k).$$
For the sequence $\{\alpha(y_{k})\}$, there is a subsequence $\{\alpha(y_{k_{j}})\}$ such that $$\lim_{j\to \infty}\alpha(y_{k_{j}})=\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} \alpha(y_k)=Y.$$
Then there is a convergent subsequence $\{y_{k_{j_i}\}}$of $\{y_{k_{j}}\}$ such that 
$$\lim_{i\to \infty} y_{k_{j_i}}=y,$$

by the continuity of $\alpha(s)$, we get 
$$\lim_{i\to \infty}\alpha(y_{k_{j_i}})=\alpha(y)=Y.$$
So $$\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} \alpha(y_k)= Y={\color{red}{\alpha(y)\leq\alpha(\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} y_k)}}.$$
The red part uses the monotonicity!